# Refer to admin site using {% url 'admin' %} in app django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

i wanna Move user to admin panel site in Django using {% url 'admin' %} but the problem is my template in rendering in an app and i dont wanna rewrite `url("^admin/",admin.site.urls)` in project/site/urls.py

here it is

#### project / urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
url(r"^", include("core.urls")),]
```

#### project / site / urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r"^$",indexView.as_view() ,name="index" ),
]
accountspattenrns = {
url(r"^accounts/signup/$",signupView.as_view() ,name="signup" ),    
url(r"^accounts/login/$",loginView.as_view() ,name="login" ),    
url(r"^accounts/logout/$",logoutView.as_view() ,name="logout" ),    
url(r"^accounts/profile/$",ProfileView.as_view() ,name="profile" ),    
}
urlpatterns +=accountspattenrns
```

#### template.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'admin' %}"><i class="fa fa-black-tie fa-2x"></i>
<div>Admin</div></a></li>
```

### Error :

[image: Error i got]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try reversing the URL using admin namespace

```
{% url 'admin:index' %}
```

Refs: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a custom name on admin.site.urls as it already exists.
As Arpit Solanki suggested, try reversing the URL using **admin namespace**

`{% url 'admin:index' %}`
For the other URLs (with names) see django/contrib/admin/sites.py file in the Django package or [reversing-admin-urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)